Distribution of test statistic after combining two sets of samples, each has a normal distributed test statistic
Suppose I recruited $N1$ patients in stage 1. During this stage, $E1$ events (e.g. death) happened.
Then, I recruited $N2$ patients in stage 2. During this stage, $E2$ events happened.
The hazard ratio (HR) among all these patients in the two stages are the same. Therefore, we can easily get the approximate distribution of log-rank test statistic:
Stage 1: $z1 \sim N(-log(HR)\sqrt{E1/4},1)$
Stage 2: $z2 \sim N(-log(HR)\sqrt{E2/4},1)$.
These two distributions are independent.
Can I say that the log-rank test statistic of these $N1+N2$ patients is: $(\sqrt{\frac{N1}{N1+N2}}z1+\sqrt{\frac{N2}{N1+N2}}z2)$ ?
(So far my simulation results support that, but I cannot rigidly prove it.)
If yes, how to prove that? if not, can we know its distribution?
ps: the distribution of $\sqrt{\frac{N1}{N1+N2}}z1+\sqrt{\frac{N2}{N1+N2}}z2 \sim N(-log(HR)\sqrt{(E1+E2)/4},1)$ for sure.
